# Trim html canvas multiple times and save location of each sprite

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm attempting to find individual sprites on a sprite sheet using html canvas & vanilla JavaScript.

[image]

I would like draw bounds and cut out each individual sprite, saving the bounds of each sprite to use later.

[image]

the sprite sheet is on a canvas called `canvas` and I would like to push the result to a canvas called `previewCanvas`

[image]

I already have a packing algorithm to create this, I just can't get my head around saving the bounds of each pixel "island"

I'm able to interrogate the `pixels.data` (below) in order to trim the redundant pixels from the edge but I can't work out how I would stop interrogating after a transparent pixel is found.

```
function cutCanvas() {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        pc = previewCanvas.getContext('2d'),
        pixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height),
        l = pixels.data.length,
        i,
        bound = {
            top: null,
            left: null,
            right: null,
            bottom: null,
        },
        x,
        y;

        for (i = 0; i < l; i += 4) {
            if (pixels.data[i + 3] !== 0) {
                x = (i / 4) % canvas.width;
                y = ~~(i / 4 / canvas.width);

                if (bound.top === null) {
                    bound.top = y;
                }

                if (bound.left === null) {
                    bound.left = x;
                } else if (x < bound.left) {
                    bound.left = x;
                }

                if (bound.right === null) {
                    bound.right = x;
                } else if (bound.right < x) {
                    bound.right = x;
                }

                if (bound.bottom === null) {
                    bound.bottom = y;
                } else if (bound.bottom < y) {
                    bound.bottom = y;
                }
            }
        }
 

    // Calculate the height and width of the content
    var trimHeight = bound.bottom + 1 - bound.top,
        trimWidth = bound.right + 1 - bound.left,
        trimmed = ctx.getImageData(
            bound.left,
            bound.top,
            trimWidth,
            trimHeight
        );

    pc.canvas.width = trimWidth;
    pc.canvas.height = trimHeight;
    pc.putImageData(trimmed, 0, 0);

    return pc.canvas;
}
```

Comment: Seems you are going the hard way =) First, start with 1 circle on an input canvas. And create a function that will return a coordinates of the bounding box for that circle. Is it possible for you?

Comment: unfortunately that's not possible. I always start with an image with sprites on

Comment: You can use this one, it has only one circle: https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-052dab97d32d037f7c28e69f87c189cf